# C++ std::sort function gets not finished?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sorting

im currently setting up the highscore-part for a game and I have a very weird problem because of the weird behaviour of the std::sort function.

Im doing the whole thing in RAD Studio 10.2 (Embarcadero IDE) in C++.

So he is my code:

```
std::string Line;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
ifstream File("Highscore.txt");
if(File.is_open())
{
    while(getline(File, Line))
    {
        count += 1;

    }

    File.close();

}

ifstream ReadFile("Highscore.txt");
if(ReadFile.is_open())
{
    string *scores = NULL;
    scores = new string[count];

    while(getline(ReadFile, Line))
    {
        scores[i] = Line;
        i += 1;
    }

    ReadFile.close();


    std::sort(scores, (scores+count));

    UnicodeString Uscores1 = scores[0].c_str();
    UnicodeString Uscores2 = scores[1].c_str();
    UnicodeString Uscores3 = scores[2].c_str();
    UnicodeString Uscores4 = scores[3].c_str();
    UnicodeString Uscores5 = scores[4].c_str();
    LScore1->Caption = Uscores1;
    LScore2->Caption = Uscores2;
    LScore3->Caption = Uscores3;
    LScore4->Caption = Uscores4;
    LScore5->Caption = Uscores5;

}
```

I get no errors from the compiler/linker and everything work should fine.
The string array gets filled correctly and so on.

But its not sorting.

To show the problem to you I made a screenshot - on the left you can see the txtfile with the scores; on the right you can see the output after the sorting algorithm:

[image]

My question now is why this is happening?

Thanks for you help

Comment: It does sort. If you want to sort numerically you should use a number type.

Comment: In case no one has told you this before, please take a look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't post a screenshot of the data, hard-code it into your example.

Comment: I was wrong and deleted my comment seconds after posting.

Comment: When I have like in the example 5 scores in my txtfile and output scores[4] the output is 5 = fifth item in my txtfile.

Comment: @SamyDressel you have 5 scores and 2 "empty" lines, which are all valid values for `std::string`. Check the value of `count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to C++.  Since you want to list numbers by rank, read them as `int` not `string`. Forget about operator `new`. You will not need it for years, if ever. Use standard containers like `std::vector`, which take care of the memory allocation and de-allocation transparently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> scores;
    {
        ifstream inp("Highscore.txt");
        int next;
        while (inp >> next) {
            scores.push_back(next);
        }
    }
    sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());
    for (auto s : scores) {
        cout << s << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me the reason why you downvoted my answer?

Comment: Thanks you - this helped me a lot. And it gave me a reason to figure out about the C++ and containers :D In a one year module developing software with C++ at my university nobody ever mentioned things like vectors. This is sad :D

Comment: Sad indeed, but typical. Decades have gone into making C++ easy to do. Students are taught to do things in ways that are not only error-prone, but would be completely unacceptable in a real-world code review. https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
int i = 0;
int * scoresInteger = NULL;
scoresInteger = new int[count];
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    scoresInteger[i] = std::stoi(scores[i]);
}
std::sort(scoresInteger, scoresInteger + count);
```

If you need to, you can convert the integers back into strings using `targetStrings[i] = std::to_string(scoresInteger[i])`.

```
string * targetScores = NULL;
targetScores = new std::string[count];
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    targetScores[i] = std::to_string(scoresInteger[i]);
}
delete [] scoresInteger;
scoresInteger = NULL;
```

Don't forget to `delete [] targetScores` later.

Comment: Please `delete` the memory for the array since you are allocating it. Copying this code will result in memory leak.

Comment: @PetarVelev Or you know... use std::vector

Answer (score 0):

> My question now is why this is happening?

Because your scores are compared as `string`s and not as `int`s. Because of that "3" is greater that "25"

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (std::string("3") > std::string("25")) << std::endl; // true
```

Luckily you can pass a custom comparator (or lambda) to the `std::sort` to make it behave just as you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const int count = 5;
    std::string scores[count] = { "35","25","3","4","5" };

    // TWEAKED SORT
    std::sort(scores, scores + count, [](std::string const &s1, std::string const &s2)
    {
        return std::stoi(s2) < std::stoi(s1);
    });

    // TEST
    for (auto const &s : scores)
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The compared `string`s in the above example are converted to `int`s and then compared, resulting in the [desired sorting order](https://ideone.com/pGQZxn).

```
35
25
5
4
3
```

Please note that I do not agree with the rest of your code and I think you should rethink the implementation, as it would be much easier, safer and more efficient to use `std::vector<std::string>` for your task.

Comment: You [asked why Jive downvoted your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982613/c-stdsort-function-gets-not-finished/49984890#comment86990140_49986518) (though I have no idea why you assume Jive was responsible; it's equally likely his answer drew attention to this question, and a subsequent visitor downvoted), and I can give you at least one reason for a downvote (I haven't, but it's a big enough error that some might). In your demonstration of string comparisons, you compared a pair of C-style strings, not `std::string`, and the result of that comparison is not always `true`…

Comment: …because C-style strings compare pointer addresses (technically, comparing pointers that aren't both pointing inside the same array is undefined behavior IIRC, but in practice, it works predictably on all machines with flat memory models). Thus, if the data backing `"3"` is stored in the binary before the data backing `"25"`, then the result is false, and if it's stored after, it's true (and this could vary between compilers, or even recompiles with the same compiler). You'd need `std::string("3") > "25"` or (w/C++14+ & `using namespace std::literals`) `"3"s > "25"s` to work as expected.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Fair enough, valid point and I corrected it, thanks. Was it worth a downvote without explanation? I personally would have left a comment and let the poster respond. As per who downvoted it, let's say I have irrefutable proof who did it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe in downvoting for errors without explaining (total garbage answers, that aren't so much inaccurate as bewildering, get downvotes without explanation, and I'll downvote without explaining if someone else explained their downvote and I agree), and when I do downvote and explain, I'll retract them when the issue is fixed (if I notice it later), but yeah, there is no justification for silent downvotes for isolated, hard-to-spot errors. That said, I've just gotten used to the occasional spurious unexplained downvote; I recheck myself, then shrug and move on.